# How can I download the ConnectedApp Usage information?

Tags: reporting, connected-apps, admin

My user has requested me to download the connected app usage for a particular app in our org. I am able to see the information on here via the UI, but I don't see a mechanism to download this to an excel file.

[image: Connected App Usage]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a download button on that page that I am aware of, but the usage information for a connected app can be queried through the [OauthToken](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_oauthtoken.htm) object.

```
list<OauthToken> oalist = [
    SELECT AppName, UserId, CreatedDate, LastUsedDate, UseCount 
    FROM OauthToken 
    WHERE AppName = '<app-name>'
];
```